# Linebreaks in CartoDB info window?

Tags: carto

I have a "notes" field in my CartoDB table, that I tried to populate with multi-line texts, but there doesn't seem to be a way to add line breaks. If I use `<br />` I just end up with a literal `<br />` in my info window.

Can I force a line break?

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251638/mustache-js-allow-only-line-breaks-escape-other-html

Comment: It would be helpful to include the solution you found as an answer for future readers.  The link in addition to a description of the solution would be helpful.

Comment: What was your solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21251638/mustache-js-allow-only-line-breaks-escape-other-html

**Option 1** - Use a pre tag:

It's actually best (or efficient) that you wrap text in a `<pre></pre>` tag, which will preserve the white space in the text.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre

And enable word-wrap

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248011/how-do-i-wrap-text-in-a-pre-tag
 - http://jsfiddle.net/X5ZY7/

**Option 2** - Split your string into lines, and use a mustache each:

```
comment = userComment.split("\n")


{{#comment}}
    {{comment}}<br/>
{{/comment}}
```

**Option 3** - Manually escape your string using your [favorite method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities) before injecting the 
 tags:

```
var div = document.createElement("div")
div.textContent = comment
comment = div.innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>")


{{{comment}}}
```

Comment: Which of these 3 options did you actually use in cartodb?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the `<br>` tags inside the `notes` column and signal to mustache.js not to strip the html in that column by using a "triple mustache" around that column in the custom html pane for your info-window: `{{{notes}}}`

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30201804/4047679)